# Create or update rails on duplicate object

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

The current code crates a duplicate object and changes some of the attributes, now I want create or update a row in db, for update I have to lookup on all the attributes except (entity_count, failed_entity_count, row_count)

```
peak_row = row.dup
peak_row[:entity_count] = 10
peak_row[:row_count] = 30
peak_row[:failed_entity_count] = 20
peak_row[:feature_type] = 'peak'
peak_row[:transaction_type] = 'write'
peak_row.save
```

What is the best way to do it.

Comment: Would first_or_initialize work for you? https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_initialize

Comment: yeah it worked already. thanks.